# FLAML returning error for gpt4 invalid API KEY

Tags: python, machine-learning, openai-api

I am trying to run this code in Visual Studio in FLAML but I keep receiving this error message:

```
InvalidRequestError: The model `gpt-4` does not exist or you do not have access to it
```

I have tried to integrate an API KEY for gpt-4 in the code but it does not work.

The code is:

```
from flaml import autogen

config_list = autogen.config_list_from_json(
    "OAI_CONFIG_LIST",
    filter_dict={
        "model": ["gpt4", "gpt-4-32k", "gpt-4-32k-0314", "gpt-4-32k-v0314"],
    },
)

llm_config={
    "request_timeout": 600,
    "seed": 42,
    "config_list": config_list,
    "temperature": 0,
}

# create an AssistantAgent instance named "assistant"
assistant = autogen.AssistantAgent(
    name="assistant",
    llm_config=llm_config,
)
# create a UserProxyAgent instance named "user_proxy"
user_proxy = autogen.UserProxyAgent(
    name="user_proxy",
    human_input_mode="TERMINATE",
    max_consecutive_auto_reply=10,
    is_termination_msg=lambda x: x.get("content", "").rstrip().endswith("TERMINATE"),
    code_execution_config={"work_dir": "web"},
    llm_config=llm_config,
    system_message="""Reply TERMINATE if the task has been solved at full satisfaction.
Otherwise, reply CONTINUE, or the reason why the task is not solved yet."""
)

# the assistant receives a message from the user, which contains the task description
user_proxy.initiate_chat(
    assistant,
    message="""
Who should read this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.08155
""",
)
```

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your post to include the full error trace (and remove any code that may come *after* the error) - see how to create a [mre]

Comment: Does your account actually have access to gpt-4? What happens if you try, say, gpt-3.5-turbo? We don't have enough information to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi, this is the full Error message : "InvalidRequestError: The model `gpt-4` does not exist or you do not have access to it. Learn more: https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7102672-how-can-i-access-gpt-4."

I am trying to make work an example of FLAML code I found here, but I don't understand how to make it work with the APY of gtp4 --> https://github.com/microsoft/FLAML/blob/main/notebook/autogen_agentchat_web_info.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Go to openai API page then rate limits:

[image: rate limits]

Check if you have gpt-4 model here, else you have to update your payemnt plan or use gpt 3.5 models